# Using PCA and StandardSclaler

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

x1 = sc.fit_transform(x)
x1 = pca.fit_transform(x1)

c_val = cross_val_score(svm.SVC(gamma='auto', C=20, kernel='linear'), x,y, cv=3 )

print(c_val,'\n------\nAverage cross value score is :', np.mean(c_val))
```

I ran `cross_val_score` for my original input and I standardised using `StandardScaler` and `PCA`
, then run `cross_val_score`, but I got less score when I used `StandardScaler`. The dataset I used was the famous titanic dataset.

My question is though standardization does not improve my score, why is it making my model perform bad?

Comment: Can you post your full code so so that your result can be reproduced? It's difficult to identify the exact cause of this issue otherwise.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.